# Removing a subclass object from parent?

Tags: java, android

I have a static `ArrayList` that holds all objects of type `VisibleObject`.
All `VisibleObjects` are also a subclass of `BaseClass` which can be a parent of a lot of classes.

My problem is that `VisibleObject` remove call is being called, but for some reason it's not actually being removed from the `ArrayList` as the size increases.

Now `VisibleObject` is added when a new `VisibleObject` is created.

Here is the problem code.

```
//Remove base class and visible object.
    List<BaseClass> baseClassList = this.mBaseClassExtras;
    Iterator<BaseClass> baseClassIterator = baseClassList.iterator();
    while(baseClassIterator.hasNext())
    {
        BaseClass baseClass = baseClassIterator.next(); // must be called before you can call i.remove()
        baseClass.update(delta);

        if(baseClass.getIsCompleted())
        {
            if(baseClass instanceof VisibleObject)
            {
                if(VisibleObject.AllVisibleObjects.remove(baseClass))
                {
                    Functions.out("VisibleObject removed.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Functions.out("Failed to remove VisibleObject - Possible memory problems.");
                }
            }

            //Remove the base class.
            baseClassIterator.remove();
        }
    }

    //BaseClass
    if(mBaseClassExtras.size() > 0)
    {
        Functions.out(
                "Is called, VisibleObjects array:" + VisibleObject.AllVisibleObjects.size() +
                " | BaseClass size: " + mBaseClassExtras.size()
        );
    }
```

Here is the output from System (Partial)

```
06-15 06:49:36.793    9301-9301/com.youllneverknowmycompany.topsecretapp I/System.out﹕ OLLY_SYSTEM: VisibleObject     removed.
06-15 06:49:36.793    9301-9301/com.youllneverknowmycompany.topsecretapp I/System.out﹕ OLLY_SYSTEM: Is called, VisibleObjects array:105 | BaseClass size: 11
06-15 06:49:36.825    9301-9301/com.youllneverknowmycompany.topsecretapp I/System.out﹕ OLLY_SYSTEM: Is called, VisibleObjects array:105 | BaseClass size: 12
06-15 06:49:36.857    9301-9301/com.youllneverknowmycompany.topsecretapp I/System.out﹕ OLLY_SYSTEM: VisibleObject removed.
06-15 06:49:36.857    9301-9301/com.youllneverknowmycompany.topsecretapp I/System.out﹕ OLLY_SYSTEM: Is called, VisibleObjects array:104 | BaseClass size: 11
06-15 06:49:36.893    9301-9301/com.youllneverknowmycompany.topsecretapp I/System.out﹕ OLLY_SYSTEM: Is called, VisibleObjects array:105 | BaseClass size: 11
06-15 06:49:36.925    9301-9301/com.youllneverknowmycompany.topsecretapp I/System.out﹕ OLLY_SYSTEM: Is called, VisibleObjects array:105 | BaseClass size: 12
06-15 06:49:36.977    9301-9301/com.youllneverknowmycompany.topsecretapp I/System.out﹕ OLLY_SYSTEM: VisibleObject removed.
```

Comment: Looks to me like there's a single element alternately being added and removed. Where do you see a problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by putting chain linking a method that was the same name in both classes. When the method was called it removed the ArrayList item from the class that stored it (static).

Then it goes to the parent class and does the standard way of removing it's self. Works perfect!